# small airborne microorganisms, are in many instances attached to bigger particulate substances?

Tags: bacteriology, virology

From https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/90193/56476

> very small airborne microorganisms, are in many instances attached to bigger particulate substances in the air, whether liquid micro droplets or solid particles. ... but this may be reason for higher risk of respiratory infectious diseases when PM2.5 air pollution gets high.

Can someone confirm this great logic?

I think it is true, but just need a confirm from the public! :)

Many thanks.

Comment: You should surely address your concern about this to the person whose answer you are quoting, asking for evidence to support the statement, rather posting a separate question. If you really must post a separate question, you need to show that you’ve tried to find the answer yourself.

Comment: I don't know about air, but that's totally true for water: turbidity is a measure of water particulates, and micro-organisms naturally attach to particulates and feed from them.